# How to add meta tag in react website view on page source?

Tags: reactjs, web, seo, metadata, meta-tags

I am Using React Helmet NPM Package Plugin But My Website Meta Tag not Show on index.html in public folder

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWqSh.png)

I am reading and watched out many blogs and Videos but not anyone can tell proper meta tag how to show on react website.